# phpstorm selecting text

Tags: phpstorm

I don't know what I did, but I'm not able to select text normally anymore like I used to - from line to line.

Right now it's behaving like if you were to old the option key on mac to select text.

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You've enabled **Column Selection Mode**, it can be toggled from the **Edit** menu or with the corresponding keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 11):

Toggling between line and column selection modes

To toggle between the line and the column selection modes, do one of the following:

On the main menu, choose **Edit | Column Selection Mode**.
On the context menu of the editor, choose Column Selection Mode.
Press **Shift+Alt+Insert**.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/selecting-text-in-the-editor.html?origin=old_help

Comment: There is no "insert" key on a mac

Answer (score 7):

On mac you'r shortcut is ⇧+⌘+8 (shift+command+8)

Answer (score 1):

I like using VSCode keybindings on mac, and for me the hotkey was 
shift+option+left click